# What is optimized way: having a sort_union or having 2 different queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have followig query which I am trying to optimize as have millions of data in the table. I tried out MySql Explain but not getting the optimized way to perform the query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE (SEND ='abc' AND TYPE IN ('A', 'D') and FLAG !='Y') 
       OR (REC ='abc' AND TYPE = 'I' and FLAG !='Y')
```

This query is using index_merge and sort_union() as I have following two indexes:

1. On SEND and REC

2. On REC

I tried having two different queries instead hitting the server twice instead of the above that uses ref type.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE SEND ='abc' AND TYPE IN ('A', 'D') and FLAG !='Y'
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE REC ='abc' AND TYPE = 'I' and FLAG !='Y'
```

Please tell me the optimized query or better way of the two above for this problem statement as the data is too large I am not able to conclude.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Look! Optimizing all the queries not possible, Just stick to basics

1.Place index on all the columns in the Where condition.

2.Choose data type properly for example if you are sure (and changing structure is in your hand) then choose CHAR(1) for COLUMN TYPE.

More over here you are hard coded the values in where so not much left that can be done

Comment: I have both TYPE and FLAG as char(1). So what you suggest single query with sort_union is better than having two different queries?

Comment: Indeed! I would like to know how much time does this above query is taking ?

Comment: Also the exact volume of data you are dealing with!

Comment: ~25M of cardinality and it took around 0.4 sec

Answer (score 0):

The optimal query would use the two indexes and then bring the results together *without* a sort.  The sort is needed for the duplicate removal using `union`.  And that, in turn, is needed because some records might satisfy both criteria.

The following version should use each index for each component.  The second has been slightly rewritten to avoid duplicates with the first:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE (SEND = 'abc' AND TYPE IN ('A', 'D') and FLAG !='Y')
union all
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE (REC = 'abc' AND TYPE = 'I' and FLAG !='Y' and SEND <> 'abc');
```

By the way, adding `TYPE, FLAG` to your indexes would further aid performance.